# Hsqldb table encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, hsqldb

How do I set the character encoding for a specific table? E.g:

```
CREATE TABLE COMMENTS (
    ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 0, INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL,
    TXT LONGVARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

By default it's encoded as ASCII but I'd rather use UTF-8 for this one table.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that it's encoded as ASCII by default?  My reading of it was that it's UTF-8 by default, though I'm open to correction here.

If it's a TEXT table you'll can specify the encoding for the table

```
SET TABLE mytable SOURCE "myfile;encoding=UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 1):

HSQLDB certainly stores all data in Unicode (with the exception of TEXT tables where you have to specify UTF-8). Therefore you don't need to specify a character encoding for normal tables.

Comment: You did not say after all how to change the encoding. And I could not find it in the documentation. "HSQLDB certainly stores all data in Unicode" - there are many Unicode encodings, e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16 - which one does HSQLDB use by default?

Comment: Java strings are UTF-16. You cannot change this encoding.

Comment: Your answer to OP sounds like you are saying the tables are UTF-8.. Anyway I do INSERT and SELECT to/from a table (by a Java servlet on Tomcat). I do insert of data in a UTF-8 Java file (that's my OS default). How is it inserted correctly then? And then I select this data and print to a web page but only see `???????`... how to make it work? I have set `httpServletResponse.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");`

Comment: Ask your own question.

Comment: I have asked actually.. still looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you must convert all rows before import.
To do this you must export the contents to a file and converter the file into utf-8. Then import it again with utf-8 options.

MyPHPadmin can import it with utf-8 options, (Remember to check for CHARSET=latin1 / latin1  in the file).

You can read more about to do it manually her: http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Convert_latin1_to_UTF-8_in_MySQL

Comment: Sorry I have not seen that it was HyperSQL you talked about. But I hope it will help you.