# HSQLDB / PHP / Tomcat 8 / Quercus - Insert non-English chars

Tags: java, php, tomcat, hsqldb, quercus

```
INSERT INTO words (word, meaning) VALUES ('Цветок', 'Flower')
```

When I execute this SQL statement from an SQL client (DbVisualizer), the values in the table look exactly like you see them here in the statement, i.e. `Цветок` is not encoded.

When I execute it from **PHP over Tomcat 8 / Java version "1.8.0_101" (Quercus 4.0.39)** , the values in the table are encoded exactly as if I would run the PHP [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on them. So `Flower` is not changed, but `Цветок` is - now it looks in the table through the SQL client like `Ð¦Ð²ÐµÑÐ¾Ðº`

Why is there difference between running the SQL statement from the client or from PHP?

How can I insert this data from PHP so that it will be saved in the database unchanged?

**UPDATE**

Here is my Tomcat context.xml HSQLDB Resource:

```
  <Resource name="jdbc/mydb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="me" password="kjsfhsjhfsd" driverClassName="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"
               url="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/mydb?characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
```

The `characterEncoding=UTF-8` is actually MySql specific (so having it breaks this resource!). What is the HSQLDB equivalent? I could not find...

I also tried to set the `php.ini` with `unicode.semantics=on` as explained here:

http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/quercus.xtp#php.ini

http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/quercus.xtp#Internationalization-16-bitunicode

http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/quercus.xtp#encoding

However, it did not make any change...

Comment: What is the collation of the field?

Comment: @Peter I have not changed the default settings.

Comment: Lookup the code page of your source php file, if it is UNICODE then what you see is double byte chars as single char bytes, that will explain the doubled lenth of the word as it looks in the table

Comment: @TSion.D.P `$ file -bi script.php` gives `text/x-php; charset=utf-8`, and I read that HSQLDB also uses this encoding by default http://stackoverflow.com/a/8696754/784980 so it looks like wrong direction

Comment: Hmmm.. I just try on the web site I'm working on, typing Cyrilic text in a form and it works. Here are my datas: MariaDB 10.1, fields in utf8mb4_unicode_ci. My PHP pages have <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" />. I run PHP7.0.19. I've used two HTML fieds: one input, the other textarea. Notice than in the destination  page, before the INSERT I perform a mysqli_real_escape_string on the values. While looking in the db, data are in Cyrilic and then the display is OK (no treatment before dsplaying)

Comment: I forget one point: after my mysqli_connect, I do a @mysqli_set_charset($handle,'utf8'); Without this I loose the portugues special char I need for my web site and the Cyrilic don't work.

Comment: @Peter my situation is different. I run PHP over Tomcat (with Quercus). And I use HSQLDB. It looks like the problem is how Tomcat speaks to HSQLDB, since directly from the client it works.